# update array of object base on property value using es6 map

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this array of object

```
[
  {
    "name": "Alice",
    "age": 10
  },
  {
    "name": "Samantha",
    "age": 20
  },
  {
    "name": "Mary",
    "age": 19
  }
]
```

How can I update Alice's age to 11?

I tried using map of es6

```
const newage = 11;
 const newDate = person.map(obj => 
      return 'Alice' === obj.name ? obj.age= newage : obj
    )
```

The reason why I map instead of normal for loop is that I do not want to mutate the origin person object, is that correct?

Comment: *"is that correct"* No. `.map` will create a new array, but `obj.age= newage` will still mutate the object. `.map` already existed before ES6 btw.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that as you loop through the array with `Array.map`, the objects you access and update the age with are still the originals, and you push the exact same objects to the new array that `Array.map` creates.

So an intuitive way to fix this, is to clone new objects and update the new objects. I made a [example](https://jsfiddle.net/dawchihliou/xf9tvtjb/) for you so you can see the outcome.

```
const original = [
  {"name": "Alice","age": 10},
  {"name": "Samantha","age": 20},
  {"name": "Mary","age": 19}
];
const newage = 11;
const newData = original.map(obj => {
  // clone the current object
  const newObj = Object.assign({}, obj);
  // update the new object
  if (newObj.name === 'Alice') newObj.age = newage;
  return newObj;
});
```