# How to rename fileds in object or fetch it's data to other object with new field?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I didn't find the answer here, so please to do no write that it is duplicate!
My problem is as follows. I have such an array with objects:

```
Items: [

        {  groups: [{…}]
          id: 1
          name: "Test Name"
          _test: null
          _test2: 0.02867696
        },
        {  groups: [{…}]
          id: 2
          name: "Test Name2"
          _test: null
          _test2: 0.02867696
        },
  ]
```

I need to change each object fields names, such as id, name to topicId and topicName. The rest on the data I need to keep as it is and return back array with changed objects.
I wrote such a function to get access to every object:

```
function changeFields(data) {
  for (const key of Object.keys(data)) {
    data[key].map(item => {

    })
  }
}
```

but I do not know what to do next.

Comment: Pretty sure you can find some questions similar to yours in here, like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42660607/update-array-of-object-base-on-property-value-using-es6-map

Comment: no because there they update data that object has but  not filed names

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` method of array to modify each entry and reassign it.

```
let Items = [
  {
    groups: [
      1, 2
    ],
    id: 1,
    name: "Test Name",
    _test: null,
    _test2: 0.02867696
  }, {
    groups: [
      1, 2
    ],
    id: 2,
    name: "Test Name2",
    _test: null,
    _test2: 0.02867696
  }
]

Items = Items.map(item => ({
  group : item.group,
  topicId : item.id,
  topicName : item.name,
  _test : item._test,
  _test2 :item._test2
}))
```

Or you have many field in array and only want to change one or two filed you can write general solution like this :

```
Items = Items.map(item => {
  let obj = {};

  //Loop trough each fields of item
  Object.keys(item).filter(key => {
    switch (key) {

      //Fields to be changed
      case 'id':
        obj['topicId'] = item['id']
        break;
      case 'name':
        obj['topicName'] = item['name']
        break;
      //End

      //Rest will be the same
      default:
        obj[key] = item[key]
    }
  })
  //Return modified obj
  return obj;
})
```

Comment: items it is object key, not let items =[] but items: [{}]

Answer (score 0):

As per your question you are trying to modify existing `array` of `objects`. Below are the pseudo steps

1. Loop through array using `map` or any equivalent method
2. Clone the object
3. Add new property with desired key to cloned object and it's value will be value associated with existing key
4. Delete old key from the object

Below is the sample code for your data and in that code i am modifying key `id` to `_id`

```js
var data = [
        {  
          groups: [{}],
          id: 1,
          name: "Test Name",
          _test: null,
          _test2: 0.02867696
        },
        {  
          groups: [{}],
          id: 2,
          name: "Test Name2",
          _test: null,
          _test2: 0.02867696
        }
  ];
var modifiedData = data.map((item) => { 
  let _item = Object.assign(item, {});
  _item['_id'] = item['id'];
  delete _item['id'];
  return _item;
});

console.log(modifiedData);
```

Comment: data it is not variable, it is key in complex object

Comment: data: [{}, {}, {}]